# Are there any programs to record through a microphone that work inside a web browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, web, audio-recording

I had a someone ask me if it were possible to record a person's voice inside of a web-browser - similar to what can be done on many operating systems. Is this possible through javascript or flash? Are there any programs that let you do this, and have the wav/mp3 of the recorded audio uploaded to the server? I'd prefer the solution to not use Flash if it can be avoided.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375328/flash-is-it-possible-to-record-the-user-voice-act-on-it

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Any for Javascript? My application isn't flash so I want to see if there's a non-flash alternative first. I actually need this to talk to my server so I hope I don't have to an all-flash solution. That would really suck.

Comment: https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers

Comment: @ToddBFisher "The patched WebKit version that we're using is an internal prototype". Since that blog post was written, almost two years ago, the device element they refer to has been removed from the HTML5 specs.

Comment: @Lars, good to know as I was planning on doing some audio recording myself soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WAMI-Recorder](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/). It still uses flash, but is designed to work with Javascript and data can be sent with HTTP POST. However, there's no way to access the microphone with Javascript alone.

At the moment, Chrome is the only browser that supports [x-webkit-speech](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5-whats-new/template/index.html#8) which is what they use to allow users to use voice to search Google on their desktop. HTML5 has `getUserMedia`, but support for that is also minimal and if your project is for mass consumption then it's unlikely to be a suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out this post where i replied to a guy with a similar question as you.

[How do I embed a Flash audio recorder in my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704852/how-do-i-embed-a-flash-audio-recorder-in-my-site/6707803#6707803)

I have done extensive research into client side only microphone recording and could not come up with any solution other than flash. If you follow my correct answer in the thread i posted, you can record audio from a microphone on the client side and then you can modify the code yourself and upload the audio to your server, its not that hard just a simple POST call.

If you do find a non-flash way to record let us know!